# How can I create a Visual Studio "Add Reference" item to import my C# COM functions as well as the C++ DLL's that these functions rely on?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, com

We have a collection of C# functions (in a DLL) that are to be passed over COM, to be easily access from Visual Studio via the "Add Reference" feature. I've setup the registry such that it indeed shows it under Extensions when clicking Add Reference on a Visual Studio C# project.

However, the C# COM DLL calls on a C++ DLL. When I create a test C# project and then click "Add Reference" to add my C# COM DLL, it succeeds in adding the class, but does not include the C++ DLL, thus causing it to fail in the build process.

Manually adding the C++ DLL into the output causes it to function properly, but it would be nice to be able to click "Add Reference" and all of the necessary files are built into the output.

I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019), creating the proper entry in the registry to the folder where *both* the C++ DLL and the C# DLL are located, but it doesn't seem to include it when simply clicking "Add Reference."

How would I go about getting my desired results? Note that the C++ DLL does not use any COM interface, it is just a standard DLL that exports functions and the C# COM DLL uses DllImport to access them.

Comment: C++ DLL's (fully native) cannot be included in the "Add Reference" items. Those items can only be managed DLL's. This would require you adding it to the project as a project item then having it copy it to the build folder. Either that, or you should be able to add the C++ DLL location to the `PATH` variable without copying it to the output directory...

Comment: Aw OK, that makes sense. I didn't even think to simply add the C++ DLL to the path, but that's a simple and easy solution and it shouldn't cause any issues in our strategy. I appreciate the response! Thank you man.